# self restarting daemon in python in *nix system

Tags: python, daemon

I need to created a daemon in python. I did search and found a good piece of [code](http://www.jejik.com/articles/2007/02/a_simple_unix_linux_daemon_in_python/). The daemon should be started automatically after system boots and it  should be started if it was unexpectedly closed. I went through chapter about daemons in [Advanced programming in the Unix environment](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201563177) and have two questions.

To run script automatically after the boot I need put my daemon script to /etc/init.d. Is that correct?

What should I do to respawn the daemon? According to the book I need add a respawn entry into /etc/inittab, but I don't have /etc/inittab on my system. Should I create it by myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a daemon, use double fork() as shown in the code you found.
Then you need to write an init script for your daemon and copy it into /etc/init.d/.

http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/feature/15380.html

There are many ways to specify how the daemon will be auto-started, e.g., chkconfig.

http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/chkconfig8.html

Or you can manually create the symlinks for certain runlevels.

Finally you need to restart the service when it unexpectedly exits. You may include a respawn entry for the serivce in /etc/inittab.

http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl5_inittab.htm

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you look into [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) if you're on Ubuntu. It's way better than `inittab` but does involve some learning curve to be honest.

**Edit** (by Blair): here is an adapted example of an upstart script I wrote for one of my own programs recently. A basic upstart script like this is fairly readable/understandable, though (like many such things) they can get complicated when you start doing fancy stuff.

```
description "mydaemon - my cool daemon"

# Start and stop conditions. Runlevels 2-5 are the 
# multi-user (i.e, networked) levels. This means 
# start the daemon when the system is booted into 
# one of these runlevels and stop when it is moved
# out of them (e.g., when shut down).
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

# Allow the service to respawn automatically, but if
# crashes happen too often (10 times in 5 seconds) 
# theres a real problem and we should stop trying.
respawn
respawn limit 10 5

# The program is going to daemonise (double-fork), and
# upstart needs to know this so it can track the change
# in PID.
expect daemon

# Set the mode the process should create files in.
umask 022

# Make sure the log folder exists.
pre-start script
    mkdir -p -m0755 /var/log/mydaemon
end script

# Command to run it.
exec /usr/bin/python /path/to/mydaemon.py --logfile /var/log/mydaemon/mydaemon.log
```

Comment: I edited in an example upstart script from one of my projects, hope you don't mind.

Comment: If you're using [python-daemon](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/) as well, then note that the 'expect daemon' stanza is best avoided - python-daemon will spot that you're using upstart and will not double fork.